# Which "Stargate" actor played the same role in "Stargate Atlantis"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

Wikipedia says this about [Richard Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Kind):

> In 2006, he guest starred on Stargate Atlantis as Lucius Lavin, in the episodes "Irresistible" and "Irresponsible," making him the only actor to appear in both the original Stargate film, and in Stargate Atlantis as different characters.

Did anyone appear in both the original Stargate film, and in Stargate Atlantis as the *same* character? I can't think of anyone... Is it simply a misleading paragraph?

Comment: I think that they are just making the distinction that he appeared in both, *but* as *different* characters. So that people don't get confused and assume that he plays the same character.

Comment: @NominSim: OK - I think the language is slightly off then, since it's describing something he's the only one to do, not an isolated fact.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?roles=tt0111282,tt0374455 -  Richard Kind is the only *Actor* listed as having been in both. There were several other credited crew who worked on both films, notably in the sound and music depts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The statement is correct. Richard Kind played a scientist named Gary Meyers in the movie, and Lucius Lavin in the Pegasus galaxy in Stargate Atlantis. To my knowledge, he's the only actor that appeared in both the movie and Stargate Atlantis, regardless of role.

However, there were a few actors who appeared in both the movie and SG-1 as the same character.

French Stewart was in the original movie and played a different role in Stargate Universe.

Comment: It's certainly correct - it's just that it implies something else that I disagree with. And so you do :)

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: I'm not sure how. I think it's pretty clear! In my view the Wikipedia paragraph implies, with its wording, that there was some actor that played the _same_ role in both the movie and SGA. Neither you nor I can think of one, so I will conclude that it's merely slightly misleading wording.

Comment: You are basically complaining about punctuation in the Wikipedia article.   I fixed it.